# I am trying to run Excel read and write by clicking a button on the front end

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I can extract text from an excel file, and in the same JS file I can write text to an excel file.  I’m using require in order to get it done.  It all runs perfectly if I press “run code” in VS Code.

However, if I want to attach a button to either the write or read function, nothing works in the Vs code console, and in the browser console it says “require is not defined”.

I understand what this means things that are browser related can’t function alongside backend, but can anyone give some tips as to how to get around it?

I have tried loads of things, as well as using module.exports to send an object into another js file.  But no matter what I do, it either says require is not defined or it says certain document related stuff is not defined even though they work perfectly independently.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

var html = "";

global.document = new JSDOM(html).window.document;

let btnOverWrite = global.document.querySelector('.btnOverWrite')
box = global.document.querySelector('.divOne');


// Requiring the module
const reader = require('xlsx')



// Reading our test file
const file = reader.readFile('./project3Temp.xlsx')

let data = []

const sheets = file.SheetNames

for(let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++)
{
const temp = reader.utils.sheet_to_json(
    file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[i]])
temp.forEach((res) => {
  data.push(res)
})
}

// Printing data
console.log(data)

btnOverWrite.addEventListener("click", () => {
let XLSX = require('xlsx')

let excelFile = "ReceivingExcelFile.xlsx";
let sheetName = "Sheet1"
let workbook = XLSX.readFile(excelFile);
let ws = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];


// Overwrite worksheet
workbook.Sheets[sheetName] = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, excelFile);
```

});

If require can’t be used in the browser, how can I set things up so that I can push a button to run code that contains require?

I don’t care if it’s an event listener or just a plain button function.

I know there are some things I’m still trying to get my head around, such as, POST, request, response, .use, .get etc…. for front end and back end linking

But does the answer lie within those kind of things?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that may be what I need to do.  I just don’t understand exactly how to do everything.  It says I need to write my Excel related code as normal in Node.js.

Then I need to host code as an API. (You can do this with Express.js pretty easily).

This I don’t understand.  What does it mean by host code as an API?  Does this mean I host the code that I wrote the excel related tasks as an API, or would it refer to some new code that contains the button?

Then you can create a button that makes a fetch request to that API endpoint.

I’m not even sure if the button is supposed to be in a completely separate file or what

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use require in your JS file on front-side, your whole file will not working. Because require module it is only works based on node.js in back-end and server.

You can try

```
<script src=what you want to require></script>
```

in your html to use the module.

Or just build a server with node.js and use server to start your website, read excel file and send data to your site.